# Proving a function is continuous using preimages

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

[image]

I want to prove that f is continuous using the preimages of open subsets here. Never worked with pre images before -- can anyone help? (also would love a good definition of a preimage).

Comment: The preimage of $A$ under $f$ is the set of all points that are mapped into $A$, $$f^{-1}(A) = \{ x\in D : f(x) \in A\}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you. could you help me do this problem? I am trying to do the first direction.

Comment: Which definition of continuity do you use? (There are several equivalent ways to define it.) We have to know what we want to show.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, I could use either the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, or the sequential version.

Comment: Okay, let's take $\varepsilon$-$\delta$. Fix $x_0 \in D$. Let $U = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z-f(x_0)\rvert < \varepsilon\}$. By assumption, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $D$, so $f^{-1}(U) = D \cap W$ for some $W$ that is open in $\mathbb{C}$. Can you deduce the existence of a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $x\in D$ and $\lvert x-x_0\rvert < \delta$, then $\lvert f(x)-f(x_0)\rvert < \varepsilon$ from that?

Comment: would this $\delta$ be the radius of the ball around $x$ that is solely contained inside of $D$?

Comment: It depends what you mean. We need a $\delta > 0$ such that $D\cap B_\delta(x_0) \subset f^{-1}(U)$. How does the existence of such a $\delta$ follow from what we have?

Comment: well, we have that $f^{-1}(U) = D\cap W$ where $W$ is open, so

$D\cap B_{\delta}(x_0) \subset D\cap W$

Comment: @DanielFischer i'm not sure where I was going with that now that I realize $x_0$ is not necessarily $\in W$

Comment: It was exactly right. We have $x_0 \in f^{-1}(U) = D\cap W$, so a fortiori $x_0 \in W$, and by the openness of $W$ there is a $\delta > 0$ with $B_\delta(x_0) \subset W$.

Comment: So we have the one direction nailed. Can you do the other?

Comment: I think so @DanielFischer , I will try to come up with something in a bit ( i have to go for a few hours but I will be back) if you are still around you'll see it soon :)

and thank you!

Comment: @DanielFischer okay, here's what I haev for the other direction:

let$x,y \in D$ such that $f(x),f(y) \in U$. we know $f$ is continuous, so if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

U is open so this statement is essentially just a ball of radius $\epsilon$, but note $x,y \in f^{-1}(U)$.

close.. but how can I finish it up?

Comment: You're starting at the wrong point. You need to start with an open $U$ and show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $D$. So take $x_0 \in f^{-1}(U)$. Then choose an appropriate $\varepsilon > 0$ (use that $U$ is open), then the continuity of $f$ in $x_0$ to see that $x_0$ is an interior point of $f^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer to use continuity of $f$ don't I need two points, not just one $x_0$ ? (probably a trivial question but whatever, if there's somehow a way to do it with one point then that saves me some writing/paper) :P

Comment: Well, the points other than $x_0$ enter a bit later than $x_0$. To show that $x_0$ is an interior point, you have to show that every $y$ "sufficiently close" to $x_0$ also belongs to $f^{-1}(U)$. For "sufficiently close", you need the continuity.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh, interior point huh.. well, we haven't defined interior/boundary points in this class (analysis) yet..

Comment: Oy, how else would you show a set is open? Just show that there is a ball (disk) $B_\delta(x_0)$ with $D\cap B_\delta(x_0) \subset f^{-1}(U)$ and don't tell anybody that that just means that $x_0$ is an interior point.

Comment: @DanielFischer hah yeah that's what I was hoping to hear, guess it never hurts to be too careful.

you should have written an answer for how much youve helped me so i could at least vote ya up.